# Registration form email verification

Tags: javascript, php, email, authentication

i have a script which I have been following a tutorial - I wish to remove the email activation and ensure the users are activated once they hit sign up instead of the activation email being sent and verified?

Here is the script.

```
<?php
session_start();
// If user is logged in, header them away
if(isset($_SESSION["username"])){
    header("location: message.php?msg=NO to that weenis");
    exit();
}
?><?php
// Ajax calls this NAME CHECK code to execute
if(isset($_POST["usernamecheck"])){
    include_once("includes/db_connex.php");
    $username = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['usernamecheck']);
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
    $uname_check = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    if (strlen($username) < 3 || strlen($username) > 16) {
        echo '<strong style="color:#F00;">3 - 16 characters please</strong>';
        exit();
    }
    if (is_numeric($username[0])) {
        echo '<strong style="color:#F00;">Usernames must begin with a letter</strong>';
        exit();
    }
    if ($uname_check < 1) {
        echo '<strong style="color:#009900;">' . $username . ' is OK</strong>';
        exit();
    } else {
        echo '<strong style="color:#F00;">' . $username . ' is taken</strong>';
        exit();
    }
}
?><?php
// Ajax calls this REGISTRATION code to execute
if(isset($_POST["u"])){
    // CONNECT TO THE DATABASE
    include_once("includes/db_connex.php");
    // GATHER THE POSTED DATA INTO LOCAL VARIABLES
    $u = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['u']);
    $e = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['e']);
    $p = $_POST['p'];
    $g = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#', '', $_POST['g']);
    $c = preg_replace('#[^a-z ]#i', '', $_POST['c']);
    // GET USER IP ADDRESS
    $ip = preg_replace('#[^0-9.]#', '', getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'));
    // DUPLICATE DATA CHECKS FOR USERNAME AND EMAIL
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$u' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
    $u_check = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    // -------------------------------------------
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$e' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
    $e_check = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    // FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING
    if($u == "" || $e == "" || $p == "" || $g == "" || $c == ""){
        echo "The form submission is missing values.";
        exit();
    } else if ($u_check > 0){ 
        echo "The username you entered is alreay taken";
        exit();
    } else if ($e_check > 0){ 
        echo "That email address is already in use in the system";
        exit();
    } else if (strlen($u) < 3 || strlen($u) > 16) {
        echo "Username must be between 3 and 16 characters";
        exit(); 
    } else if (is_numeric($u[0])) {
        echo 'Username cannot begin with a number';
        exit();
    } else {
    // END FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING
        // Begin Insertion of data into the database
        // Hash the password and apply your own mysterious unique salt
        $p_hash = md5 ($p);
        // Add user info into the database table for the main site table
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, gender, country, ip, signup, lastlogin, notescheck)       
                VALUES('$u','$e','$p_hash','$g','$c','$ip',now(),now(),now())";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
        $uid = mysqli_insert_id($db_conx);
        // Establish their row in the useroptions table
        $sql = "INSERT INTO useroptions (id, username, background) VALUES ('$uid','$u','original')";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
        // Create directory(folder) to hold each user's files(pics, MP3s, etc.)
        if (!file_exists("user/$u")) {
            mkdir('user/'.$u, 0755, True);
        }
        // Email the user their activation link
        $to = "$e";                          
        $from = "hello@iamdanbarrett.com";
        $subject = 'yoursitename Account Activation';
        $message = 'message here!'.$e.'</b></div></body></html>';
        $headers = "From: $from\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        echo "signup_success";
        exit();
    }
    exit();
}
?>


<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="js/ajax.js"></script>
<script>
function restrict(elem){
    var tf = _(elem);
    var rx = new RegExp;
    if(elem == "email"){
        rx = /[" "]/gi;
    } else if(elem == "username"){
        rx = /[^a-z0-9]/gi;
    }
    tf.value = tf.value.replace(rx, "");
}
function emptyElement(x){
    _(x).innerHTML = "";
}
function checkusername(){
    var u = _("username").value;
    if(u != ""){
        _("unamestatus").innerHTML = 'checking ...';
        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "signup.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
                _("unamestatus").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
            }
        }
        ajax.send("usernamecheck="+u);
    }
}
function signup(){
    var u = _("username").value;
    var e = _("email").value;
    var p1 = _("pass1").value;
    var p2 = _("pass2").value;
    var c = _("country").value;
    var g = _("gender").value;
    var status = _("status");
    if(u == "" || e == "" || p1 == "" || p2 == "" || c == "" || g == ""){
        status.innerHTML = "Fill out all of the form data";
    } else if(p1 != p2){
        status.innerHTML = "Your password fields do not match";
    } else if( _("terms").style.display == "none"){
        status.innerHTML = "Please view the terms of use";
    } else {
        _("signupbtn").style.display = "none";
        status.innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "signup.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
               if(ajax.responseText.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, " ") == "signup_success"){
                    status.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                    _("signupbtn").style.display = "block";
                } else {
                    window.scrollTo(0,0);
                    _("signupform").innerHTML = "OK "+u+", check your email inbox and junk mail box at <u>"+e+"</u> in a moment to complete the sign up process by activating your account. You will not be able to do anything on the site until you successfully activate your account.";
                }
            }
        }
        ajax.send("u="+u+"&e="+e+"&p="+p1+"&c="+c+"&g="+g);
    }
}
function openTerms(){
    _("terms").style.display = "block";
    emptyElement("status");
}
/* function addEvents(){
    _("elemID").addEventListener("click", func, false);
}
window.onload = addEvents; */
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="pageMiddle">
  <h3>Sign Up Here</h3>
  <form name="signupform" id="signupform" onsubmit="return false;">
    <div>Username: </div>
    <input id="username" type="text" onblur="checkusername()" onkeyup="restrict('username')" maxlength="16">
    <span id="unamestatus"></span>
    <div>Email Address:</div>
    <input id="email" type="text" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" onkeyup="restrict('email')" maxlength="88">
    <div>Create Password:</div>
    <input id="pass1" type="password" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" maxlength="16">
    <div>Confirm Password:</div>
    <input id="pass2" type="password" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" maxlength="16">
    <div>Gender:</div>
    <select id="gender" onfocus="emptyElement('status')">
      <option value=""></option>
      <option value="m">Male</option>
      <option value="f">Female</option>
    </select>
    <div>Country:</div>
    <select id="country" onfocus="emptyElement('status')">
      <?php include_once("includes/template_country_list.php"); ?>
    </select>
    <div>
      <a href="#" onclick="return false" onmousedown="openTerms()">
        View the Terms Of Use
      </a>
    </div>
    <div id="terms" style="display:none;">
      <h3>Web Intersect Terms Of Use</h3>
      <p>1. Play nice here.</p>
      <p>2. Take a bath before you visit.</p>
      <p>3. Brush your teeth before bed.</p>
    </div>
    <br /><br />
    <button id="signupbtn" onclick="signup()">Create Account</button>
    <span id="status"></span>
  </form>
```

Comment: I removed the block of code where it does trigger the email but I just need it to activate the user (if that is necessary and move onto the index page).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest, you should really learn what is going on in the code instead of simply copying it out from a tutorial

The email activation occurs here

```
// Email the user their activation link
    $to = "$e";                          
    $from = "hello@iamdanbarrett.com";
    $subject = 'yoursitename Account Activation';
    $message = 'message here!'.$e.'</b></div></body></html>';
    $headers = "From: $from\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    echo "signup_success";
```

so you can simply remove this, and instead of emailing them a verification, just change their status in the database to registered or however you distinguish between someone who hasn't activated their account and someone who has activated their account.

Comment: I am at a point where I am trying to learn the code - This is the point where I remove the that block but I wasnt sure on how to auto activate the user as its set to 0 by default I believe.

Comment: I didnt copy this code its a tutorial on YouTube - his code works fine but the activation doesn't work for me but this isn't something I require...

Answer (score 2):

In order to achieve that you'll need to :

1 - learn PHP

2 - There's no 2, you'll just figure it out once you can read the code.